# Is translating my own programming language to another language and compiling it a good practice?

Tags: compiler-construction, antlr4, transpiler

I have my grammar ready and tested in Antlr4
actually I want to have my language source files to become executable and fast enough
so I think I have these solutions:

1. LLVM
2. JVM
3. Generating a source code in another language and then compile the generated file(s)

my question is about the solution number 3

what's your opinions?
is it a bad practice?
what are the challanges? and negative points?
is there any tips or suggestions here? about target lang, optimizing, any sources to read, etc

thanks

Comment: 4. Write an own backend. Keeping everything in-house has its benefits. If only because 1. and 2. are often a independently versioned quantity in your project

Comment: Interesting Marco 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get to a minimum viable product (a prototype, a version 0.01) fast I would do the 3rd. For example translate to C. I read somewhere that the hardest parts of creating a good compiler is to return good error messages and to optimize well for the intended CPU or VM. If you chose the 3rd alternative you get (some) optimization for free. And if the compiler proves to be worthwhile improving then LLVM and/or JVM and/or compile directly to binary/assembly. If you have all the time in the world. Whats best also depends on what type of language you've created I guess. First I would check if you have something unique and useful not found in other languages. If not, whats the point of adding yet another language to an already very long list?

Comment: the main goal of my language is readability and easier to write at the same time with some other extra features that also help the main goal, almost unique in it's type, atleast I've never seen like this, and can be useful to many computer user groups and also developers

Comment: "If you chose the 3rd alternative you get (some) optimization for free." You get that with all three options.

Comment: @sepp2k so does the 3rd option has pros or not in your opinion?

Comment: https://tomassetti.me/how-to-create-programming-language/

Comment: C is a great target for compilers. See this for a language & compiler with C as one of the targets: https://github.com/luciotato/LiteScript

Comment: Thank you for sharing the repo

Answer (score 0):

One huge drawback in using another text-based language as a backend for your language is in losing precise debugging information - variables, locations, etc.

If you're using a language with rich metadata, such as LLVM IR (and yes, it's not too much lower level than C anyway), you can stuff in all the debugging information you want. It's almost as easy to target LLVM as C.

Another alternative, if you want to benefit from very high level language features and build your new language on top is to use an extensible language as your base - e.g., implement your language as a syntax extension on top of Racket or Common Lisp.

Comment: Actually I am agree with you but the problem is I am not familiar with llvm and couldn't understand it...I will work on that but to start I just thought maybe it's better to target another language that I know to be able to atleast make a demo of it

Comment: @NavidDezashibi for a quick implementation something like Racket is probably the easiest way to go then. Compiling to C or even C++ is also quite easy, as long as you don't care about precise debugging information (you can have some with #line pragma).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion I'll check racket 

Comment: @NavidDezashibi more details here: https://github.com/racket/racket/wiki/Creating-Languages